# Understand array of vector notation

Tags: linear-algebra, notation

I have the following notation:

$[p_1, p_2, p_3][\alpha_1 \lambda_1,\alpha_2 \lambda_2,\alpha_3 \lambda_3]^T$

where all $\alpha$ and $\lambda$ are scalars and all $p$'s are $3x1$ vectors.

How would the final result look like (i.e. what shape would it have)? My interpretation is that I perform a dot product between $p_i$ and $[\alpha_1 \lambda_1,\alpha_2 \lambda_2,\alpha_3 \lambda_3]^T$ and end up with a $1x3$ vector.

I am supposed to be able to add this result to a vector of the form $[x,y,z]^T$ but I can't see how it can have this form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

You have:
$$
\mathbf{p_i}=\begin{bmatrix}
p_{i,1}\\p_{i,2}\\p_{i,3}
\end{bmatrix} \quad i \in\{1,2,3\}
$$
So:
$$
[\mathbf{p_1},\mathbf{p_2},\mathbf{p_3}][\alpha_1 \lambda_1,\alpha_2 \lambda_2,\alpha_3 \lambda_3]^T=
\begin{bmatrix}
p_{1,1}&p_{2,1}&p_{3,1}\\
p_{1,2}&p_{2,2}&p_{3,2}\\
p_{1,3}&p_{2,3}&p_{3,3}\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\alpha_1\lambda_1\\
\alpha_2\lambda_2\\
\alpha_3\lambda_3\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: +1. To @LukeTaylor: If you find an answer useful for you, you can *upvote* it and you may "accept" it as the answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

You have a $3 \times 3$ matrix multiplied with a $3 \times 1$ vector (note the transpose turns a $1 \times 3$ vector into a $3 \times 1$ vector). So the result is a $3 \times 1$ vector, namely $\alpha_1 \lambda_1 p_1 + \alpha_2 \lambda_2 p_3 + \alpha_3 \lambda_3 p_3$.

Comment: Thanks! I got confused with the commas in $[p1,p2,p3]$ I didn't realise it should be interpreted as a $3x3$ matrix.

Comment: @LukeTaylor Yeah, it is sort of hybrid Matlab/math notation, I think.